# How did the Death Star design flaw survive into later iterations like Death Star II and Starkiller?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, rogue-one

In the movie Rogue One the character of Galen Erso:

> Has intentionally put a thermal exhaust port as a fatal weakness in the Death Star

How is possible that this weak point still exists in the next Death Star (and even in StarKiller base)?, if is a intentionally weak point should be removed in next projects.

Comment: That is Dark Side's way of punishing you for retconning.

Comment: They don't use the exhaust port in Return, they just fly in and blow up the reactor.

Comment: Not really understanding all the DV's on the question. It is good to leave feedback if you think the question can be improved.

Answer (score 16):

Neither Death Star II, nor Starkiller Base had that weak point.

- Death Star II was unfinished, and therefore allowed the fighters to literally fly into it.
- Starkiller base was attacked via ingenious engineering solution that involved destroying containment field for the weapons energy store.

Answer (score 6):

1) The weakness Galen put in there was not the exhaust port - it was the design of the reactor. The reactor design was unstable, so that any "pressurised explosion" there would set off a chain reaction and destroy the station. The thermal exhaust port was just the way the Rebels found to get that explosion into the core quickly enough.

2) The attack on the DSII did not use a thermal exhaust port. They flew directly into the unfinished structure of the Death Star and flew to the reactor, which they destroyed. It's likely that they used the same design for the weapon of DSII as for DSI, since they didn't have Galen around to come up with a new design.

Comment: Not quite true. The thermal exhaust port is all but confirmed as Galen’s doing through several things mentioned in the novelization.

Comment: The novelisation also contains dialogue that didn't show up in the film, and Galen's hologram message is different. My understanding is that the dialogue in the film trumps the text in the novelisations.

Comment: Ehhh, where they directly contradict, yes. The expanded material in novelizations is fully canon.

Comment: Good answer, but point 2 bothers me a bit. Galen himself admits that eventually the Empire would have realized they didn't need him to complete the project, *so he made himself integral to it*. Finding a way to circumvent the fatal flaw (of the reactor chain-reaction) in the DS1 should have been the Empire's #1 priority after is the weakness was so *spectacularly revealed*

Comment: @DBPriGuy, how exactly would that information reach them, though?  It's not like the in-house engineers from the Death Star could give a report.  They're all dead.