# If the first Death Star had the weakness installed on purpose

Tags: star-wars, death-star, return-of-the-jedi

If the first Death Star's weakness was purposely built in so the rebels could destroy it according to Rogue One, is the same true for the second? Because it seems like an even bigger weakness and you would've thought something like that would've been prevented considering what happened last time.

Comment: My answer to the dupe explicitly states that they'd fixed the flaws that plagued the Death Star 1.

Comment: Also, dupey of this one; [How did the Death Star design flaw survive into later iterations like Death Star II and Starkiller?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147835/how-did-the-death-star-design-flaw-survive-into-later-iterations-like-death-star).